# Speed up slow WP CLI

Tags: wp-cli

No matter what command I execute it takes about 1,3 seconds to get it done. So it seems that there some kind of bottleneck. When I pass --skip-plugins it will be faster about. It will take about 0,9 seconds.

What does --skip-plugins actually do? I can still add it even if I use the command plugin list. I would assume that it won't load the plugins but it does.

Is there any chance to speed up the execution. I have a batch of commands and it take a long time for them to execute.

Comment: What's your PHP version? What's your memory limit? What version of WP-CLI are you using? And why don't you simply look at the code repository for --skip-plugins? WP-CLI is open source. Also 1.3s doesn't sound that bad.

Comment: @leymannx PHP Version is 7.3.1. Memory Limit ist 2048M and it's WP CLI 2.3.0. Thank you for the hint to look up the code. I will take a look and see if it makes sense for me. So you say 1.3s isn't a bad result for WP CLI commands?